# Maximize form but do not cover the taskbar

Tags: vb.net, taskbar, maximize-window

When I click the button to maximize my form, it covers the entire screen including the taskbar. I managed to find a solution and it works, I used my code in form load event but I cannot return the form into normal state.

```
Private Sub frmDashboard_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top
    Me.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left
    Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
    Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width        
End Sub

Private Sub btnMaximizeMin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMaxMin.Click
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        'maximize but dont cover taskbar
        Me.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top
        Me.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left
        Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
        Me.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
    Else
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the point of setting those four properties separately when you have get then from the `WorkingArea` to do so? Why not just assign the `WorkingArea` directly to the `Bounds` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't maximising the form. You specifically DON'T want to maximise the form because that covers the Windows Task Bar. You can't set the `WindowState` "back" to `Normal` because it's already in that state, because it never leaves that state. It's up to you to remember the state for yourself and also the previous bounds, e.g.

```vb
Private isMaximised As Boolean = False
Private normalBounds As Rectangle

Private Sub MaximiseOrRestore()
    isMaximised = Not isMaximised

    If isMaximised Then
        normalBounds = Bounds
        Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
    Else
        Bounds = normalBounds
    End If
End Sub
```